# port number assigning in UDP datagram and port number in sockaddr_in

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming

In linux:

I'm writing a code to implement UDP socket.

I want to fill udp header fields, so I must assign source and destination port numbers.

for example:

```
struct udphdr *udph    
//UDP header
udph->source = htons (6666);
udph->dest = htons (8622);
```

Also I must prepare the struct sockaddr_in, which contains a port number field, for example:

```
//internet socket structure
struct sockaddr_in sin; 
sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
sin.sin_port = htons(80);
```

Is there any relation between port number values in the sockaddr_in  structure, and these in the UDP header?

What is the correct way to assign these values?

Here is my full code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h> //sleep         
//socket headers
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <errno.h> //when socket creation failed
//#include <netinet/tcp.h>   //Provides declarations for tcp header
#include <netinet/udp.h>   //Provides declarations for udp header
#include <netinet/ip.h>    //Provides declarations for ip header
#include <stdlib.h> //for exit();
#include <string.h> //memset
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
int main()
{
    //declarations
    int sokt_fd;
    //buffers
    char datagram[80];// 80 bytes datagram
    char *data;//buffer for payload
    //code here
    //Create a udp socket
    if((sokt_fd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) <0)
    {
        //socket creation failed, may be because of non-root privileges
        perror("Failed to create socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    //zero out the packet buffer
    memset (datagram, 0, 80);
    //UDP header
    struct udphdr *udph = (struct udphdr *) datagram;//assign startof udp
    //Data part
    data = datagram + sizeof(struct udphdr);//assigin location of data
    strcpy(data , "ABC");
    //UDP header
    udph->source = htons (6666);
    udph->dest = htons (8622);
    udph->len = htons(8 + strlen(data)); //UDP header size
    //disable checksum
    udph->check = 0; //leave checksum 0 now, filled later by pseudo header
    //internet socket structure
    //destination IP address, and port
    //http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#sendtorecv
    struct sockaddr_in sin; 
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_port = htons(80);
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr ("10.0.0.2"); //destenation IP address,

    //sending the datagram:
    while(1)
    {
        if (sendto (sokt_fd,datagram,udph->len,0/*int flags*/,(struct sockaddr *) &sin, sizeof (sin))<0)
        {
            perror("sendto failed");
        }
        else
        {
            printf ("Packet Send. Length : %d \n" , udph->len);

        }
        sleep(5);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you using raw sockets for the UDP communication? Where and how  do you use the UDP header structure? Where and how do you use the `sockaddr_in` structure?

Comment: I have added the full code, kindly re-look at it.

Comment: When you use the standard functions for TCP or UDP the header (both the TCP/UDP and the IP headers) are filled in by the network stack, you don't have to do anything about it. All you have to "worry" about is the `sockaddr_in` structure used in `sendto`. You only need to worry about the headers if you use raw sockets.

Comment: If I changed the socket to raw type, how I must fill port numbers in UDP header, and sockaddr_in ?

Comment: Don't use raw sockets, unless you really need to. When communicating with normal TCP or UDP there's no need to use raw sockets (and then you have to handle the IP header as well). Use a normal UDP socket like you show in the code in your question, use the `sockaddr_in` structure, and `sendto`. That's it.

Comment: I see what you mean know. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you an IPPROTO_UDP socket, you don't mess about with the udp headers.

This is a snippet from something that sends UDP to 127.0.0.1 on port 6666.

```
struct in_addr in;
struct sockaddr_in sdest;

memset(&sdest, 0, sizeof(sdest));
sdest.sin_family = AF_INET;
sdest.sin_port = htons(6666);

inet_aton("127.0.0.1", &in);
sdest.sin_addr.s_addr = in.s_addr;
r = sendto(sock, data, size, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &sdest, (socklen_t) sizeof(sdest));
```

But you should also look at `bind` as well. This allows you to receive stuff (always useful), but mainly you should look at the excellent examples in `Unix Network Programming` by W Richard Stevens et al ISBN 0-13-141155-1.

Comment: `bind()` establishes the local ip/port used for the socket, so that can be used for setting the source ip/port for outbound packets, whereas the parameters of `sendto()` sets the destination ip/port for the packets.